# React Native - Change StatusBar color when reached a certain section

Tags: android, react-native

What can I do to change the StatusBar backgroundColor property when a certain section of the app is reached?

For example: I have a View (Section), the default backgroundColor is red, when scrolling down to that section I want to change the StatusBar backgroundColor to blue.

Here's the component where I want to do it (**NOTE: I'm using Native Base**):

```
         <Container>
            <StatusBar backgroundColor='#2c3e50' barStyle='dark-content' />
            <Content>
                <Grid>
                    <Col>
                        <Row>
                            <Text>
                                App title name
                            </Text>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Text>
                                Random description
                            </Text>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Col>
                        <Row>
                            <Text>

                            </Text>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>
                    <Row>
                        <Col style={{padding: 20, backgroundColor: '#2980b9'}}>
                            <Text style={{color: 'white', textAlign: 'justify'}}>
                                Random text
                            </Text>
                            <Text style={{ color: 'white', paddingTop: 10, textAlign: 'justify'}}>
                                More random text
                            </Text>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col style={{backgroundColor: '#1abc9c'}}>
                            <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 40, textAlign: 'center'}}>
                                Chocolate
                            </Text>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Text>
                                Random txt
                            </Text>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Grid>
            </Content>
        </Container>
```

Comment: Post what have you done instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace `Content` with `ScrollView` `reac-native` component. Add your background color in the state, then update your background color when `ScrollView` react at certain position. Use [onScroll](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#onscroll) function to detect `ScrollView` position.

**NOTE:** If `Content` native-base component is similar to `ScrollView` `reac-native` component, then you don't need to replace it. I have no experience with `native-base`

Comment: I managed to do it, but I don't find a way to make it work in any other device, because I'm using the `contentOffset.y` value of my phone. I would like to know how to calculate the location of a 'section' in Y axis in every device and make something with it.

Comment: Use [onLayout](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#onlayout) to find y position of your section.